# I am trying to print columns with space between columns in flutter using network printer but problem it show columns without space

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, network-printers

```
*printing columns inside row using network printer*
```

this is code that I used

```
import 'package:esc_pos_printer/esc_pos_printer.dart';
import 'package:esc_pos_utils/esc_pos_utils.dart';

printItem() async {
  const PaperSize paper = PaperSize.mm80;

  final profile = await CapabilityProfile.load();
  final printer = NetworkPrinter(paper, profile, spaceBetweenRows: 30);

  final PosPrintResult res =
      await printer.connect('192.168.100.30', port: 9100);

  if (res == PosPrintResult.success) {
    printer.row([
      PosColumn(
        text: 'col3',
        width: 3,
        styles: PosStyles(align: PosAlign.center, underline: true),
      ),
      PosColumn(
        text: 'col6',
        width: 6,
        styles: PosStyles(align: PosAlign.center, underline: true),
      ),
      PosColumn(
        text: 'col3',
        width: 3,
        styles: PosStyles(align: PosAlign.center, underline: true),
      ),
    ]);
    printer.row([
      PosColumn(
        text: 'col3',
        width: 3,
        styles: PosStyles(align: PosAlign.center, underline: true),
      ),
      PosColumn(
        text: 'col6',
        width: 6,
        styles: PosStyles(align: PosAlign.center, underline: true),
      ),
      PosColumn(
        text: 'col3',
        width: 3,
        styles: PosStyles(align: PosAlign.center, underline: true),
      ),
    ]);
    printer.feed(2);
    printer.cut();
    printer.disconnect();
    print('Print result: ${res.msg}');
  }
}
```

this result of the code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQM6K.jpg)
this is a link that flutters dependency that I used:
[enter link description here](https://pub.dev/packages/esc_pos_printer)
this is result that expected for columns how to be:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1BmG.jpg)

Comment: Did you find solution for this poblem?

Answer (score -1):

```
printer.row([
 PosColumn(
        text: '',
        width: 2,
        styles: PosStyles(align: PosAlign.center, underline: true),
      ),
      PosColumn(
        text: 'col3',
        width: 3,
        styles: PosStyles(align: PosAlign.center, underline: true),
      ),
 PosColumn(
        text: '',
        width: 2, #As your width size
        styles: PosStyles(align: PosAlign.center, underline: true),
      ),
      PosColumn(
        text: 'col6',
        width: 6,
        styles: PosStyles(align: PosAlign.center, underline: true),
      ),
PosColumn(
        text: '',
        width: 2,
        styles: PosStyles(align: PosAlign.center, underline: true),
      ),
      PosColumn(
        text: 'col3',
        width: 3,
        styles: PosStyles(align: PosAlign.center, underline: true),
      ),
    ]);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).